# Java - web based chat app using comet

Tags: java, chat, push

Are there any  good up to date demos or open source implementations of a web chat client using  java as a server(users should be saved in a database).
preferably a soloution that can be extended using  push/comet/json.

Comment: I used Atmosphere and I found it very good in design and documentation: 
- https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere 
- https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/tree/master/docs

Comment: Did you have a look at XMPP client and server implementations (http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/)? It's the quasi standard, some Java based implementations are available as well...